# css position left or right does not working on ie11

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position, internet-explorer-11

position absolute left or right does not show the `.box` background color in Internet Explorer 11 (IE11) at the same time all the other browsers are working fine (Please find attached screenshots)

**Unfortunately I can't put the width. because the number of images may vary**

Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qVLyaM

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrap {
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  width: 700px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.box {
  display: inline-flex;
  background-color: tomato;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  left: 100%;
  bottom: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-img"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=Logo 01"></div>
    <div class="box-img"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=Logo 01"></div>
    <div class="box-img"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=Logo 01"></div>
    <div class="box-img"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=Logo 01"></div>
    <div class="box-img"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=Logo 01"></div>
    <div class="box-img"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=Logo 01"></div>
    <div class="box-img"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=Logo 01"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why `inline-flex`? Does setting it to `flex` make any difference? (on a mac, no IE)

Comment: @Adam It was part of the testing. `flex` also fine :-)

Comment: With an extra element wrapper it will work https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gXZBpz

Comment: Plus one for that fancy hand-drawn browser name lettering :D